# How to index PDF / MS-Word / Excel files really fast for full text search?

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, search-engine, real-time

We are building real time search feature for institutions, the index is based on the user uploaded files (mostly are Word/Excel/PDF/PowerPoint, and ASCII files). The I/O is expected at only 10 IOPS -20 IOPS but it can vary depends on the date. Maximum I/O could be 100 IOPS. Current database size is reaching 10GB, it's 4 months old.

For real time search server, I'm considering Solr / Lucene and probably ElasticSearch. But the challenge is how to index these files FAST, so that search server can query the index in real time.

I have found some similar questions on how to index .doc/.xls/.pdf, but they did not mention how to ensure indexing performance:

- [Search for keywords in Word documents and index them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054902/search-for-keywords-in-word-documents-and-index-them)
- [Index Word/PDF Documents From File System To SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024543/index-word-pdf-documents-from-file-system-to-sql-server)
- [How to extract text from MS office documents in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011234/how-to-extract-text-from-ms-office-documents-in-c-sharp)
- [Using full-text search with PDF files in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272694/using-full-text-search-with-pdf-files-in-sql-server-2005)

**So my question is: how to build the index FAST ?**

Any suggestion on the architecture ? Should I focus on building fast infrastructure (i.e. RAID, SSD, more CPU, Network bandwidth ?) or focus on the index tools & algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

We're building a high perfomance full-text search for office documents. We can share some insights:

- We use ElasticSearch. It's difficult to make it perform well on large file. We write several posts about it.

  - [Highlighting Large Documents in ElasticSearch](https://blog.ambar.cloud/highlighting-large-documents-in-elasticsearch/)
  - [Making ElasticSearch Perform Well with Large Text Fields](https://blog.ambar.cloud/making-elasticsearch-perform-well-with-large-text-fields/)
- Use microservice architecture and docker to easily scale your application
- Do not store original files in elasticsearch as binary data. Store it separately for example in MongoDB

Hope it helps!